# Possible to rank the display of database results?

Tags: php, sql, html

I have a SQL database of website names/links/keywords. I then PHP query the database, and display the results with matching keywords as the name and link.

I would like to implement some kind of ranking system. Ideally it would be a clickable five-star type system (like the netflix ranking system, if you are familiar) where it saves each ranking in the database as a new value.

To clarify.. If I initially searched for 'dogs' and 3 websites returned, the default would be for them to be listed in order of their database id. I would like to be able to click a star and have that become the new determining factor on the next search display.

So if db id #1 had (3) 5-star ratings, and (1) 4-star rating, db id #2 had (8) 5-star ratings, and (1) 3-star rating, and db id #3 had (6) 5-star ratings, the results would be id #2, id #3, id #1.

I'm not sure if this is even possible. If it is, maybe someone can link me to some good reading about it.

In case there is a (semi)-easy solution, here is my current output result from the database query.

```
<?php
// query database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `database` WHERE  `keys` LIKE  '%$q%'");               
// display query results
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<b>".$row['name']."</b>";
echo "<br/>";
echo '<a href="' . $row['weblink'] . '">' . $row['weblink'] . '</a>'; 
}   
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider doing a points-based rating system rather than calculating ratings on the fly if you aren't interested in the number of votes. This would mean you only need to add a single INT column to your results table (or relational table if you must).

1 Star = 1 point, 5 stars = 5 points, or however you see fit. You could also allow points to be subtracted by adding a "This didn't help" button or something similar.

When the user selects a rating, you will simply add the points to the current rating and `UPDATE` the entry. Then of course add `ORDER BY rating DESC` when you query the db for results.

There are plenty of scripts out there, just [search google](http://www.google.com/search?q=star+ratings+php) for "star ratings php" or "5 star rating php" or even [search Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=star+rating). I don't want to endorse any particular one, but they all work pretty much the same way.

**EDIT**: Note that this simply ranks the result higher or lower, but ***not*** based on the search parameters it turned up for. That would be (quite a lot) more complicated and I wasn't thinking of it while I was answering, but hopefully this helps a bit anyways, GL!

Comment: Thanks. I found a good one here.

http://webtint.net/tutorials/5-star-rating-system-in-php-mysql-and-jquery/

It was exactly what I needed for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite easy, what I would do is save the current rank as well as the number of votes.

Then, you could simply order the table by the rating with this: `ORDER BY rating DESC`

When something recieves a new rating, you add one to the number of votes and calculate the new rating like so:

`$new_rating = ( ( $current_rating * $current_votes ) + $new_vote ) / ($current_votes + 1);`

**For example:**

An item has a current rating of 4 with 10 votes, and somebody gives a rating of 1.

`$new_rating = ( ( 4 * 10 ) + 1 ) / ( 11 );`

And the new rating is: 3.72

Comment: That's what I call a streaming average. Because your are calculation an average only knowing on value at a time.

Comment: This doesn't matter, if you would calculate the average of three values: 1, 2 and 3 this would be done like this: (1+2+3) / 3 = 2. If you were to add another value (4), you could either do this: (1+2+3+4) / 4 = 2.5. Or: (6 + 4) / 4 = 2.5

Comment: I just gave the thing a name, your perfectly right. Don't worry.